# lightning tree grid - Make one particular column editable on the child rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, inline, edit

I have an requirement where in I have to make a particular column editable on the child rows of the
lightning tree grid. I came to later on(after the development) that inline edit is not possible on lightning tree grid the same is mentioned on Salesforce developer guide.

Any workaround to achieve this, may be thru custom CSS, etc. Thanks.

Comment: That's not how CSS works. You'll have to write your own component.

Comment: Thank you. WIll do the same